# How to specify that a primary key can be null in Spring jpa

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a multiple PK : The primary key for my table is (idQuestion, id_parent).

In QuestionsId Class I've:

```
@Embeddable
public class QuestionsId implements Serializable
{
    @Column(name = "id_parent", nullable = true)
    private Integer id_parent;
    @Column(name = "idQuestion", nullable = false)
    private Integer idQuestion; 

     //Setters, Getters, etc
     }
```

In the Questions class:

```
 @EmbeddedId
    @Column(nullable = true, unique = true)
    private QuestionsId idQuestion;

      //Setters, Getters, etc
```

the id_parent **should contain null value** I've tried to put **nullable=true** but it doesn't work ! How can I specify that this PK can have a null value !?

Comment: You don't understand what primary means.

Comment: Am here to understand ! if you have a positive comment you could post it otherwise don't tell me that I don't understand. I posted bcz I really don't understand my problem !!

Comment: You don't get to decide how people advise you.  Your problem is that you're asking how to do something that makes little sense.  That's worth knowing.  Change your requirement: all questions have to have an id.

Answer (score 2):

if it can be null then it should not be primary key. primary key is a unique identifier and if one of its composite attributes could be null then there is a possibility of violating the uniqueness.

Comment: violating the uniqueness means I should remove unique = true ? because I've tried it and doesn't work !

Comment: primary key has unique constraint by default, if you do not want this constraint why you want it to be PK

Comment: In case you have a DB sequence which is controlled by a trigger before insert. The trigger needs to have null PK in order to have nextval.
DB Sequence is not accessible by user. You cannot do seq.nextval in Spring Boot